# Angular2: + operator converting number types to strings

Tags: angular, binding, operators

Can anyone explain why the '+' operator in my binding is concatenating my variables as strings, whereas other arithmetic operators such as -, * and / are correctly doing the arithmetic operations on them as numbers, which is their type in the associated typescript file.

Contents of voter.component.html

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"
(click)="UpVote()"
[class.highlighted]="myVote === 1"></i>

<span class="vote-count">{{ voteCount + myVote }}</span>

<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"
(click)="DownVote()"
[class.highlighted]="myVote === -1"></i>
```

Contents of voter.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'ui-voter',
    templateUrl: './voter.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./voter.component.css']
})
export class VoterComponent {

    @Input() voteCount: number;
    @Input() myVote: number;

    UpVote() {
        if (this.myVote === 1) { return; };
            this.myVote++;
    }

    DownVote() {
        if (this.myVote === -1) { return; };
            this.myVote--;
    }
}
```

The line in my app.component.html file which uses this component

```
<ui-voter voteCount="20" myVote="0"></ui-voter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes, `voteCount` and `myVote` are interpreted as `string` when you use double quotes to assign value, even though you explicitly declared them as `number`. This should work:

```
<ui-voter voteCount=20 myVote=0></ui-voter>
```

`+` operator can be used to concat two strings, but `-`, `*` and `/` can't operate with strings and I guess that's what created confusion. When you assign value to `number` type variables, you should always do it without quotes.

Comment: That did the trick!  Strange that it would overwrite my explicitly typed variables but there you have it!  Thanks @Stefan.